# Merge two pandas Dataframes adding multiindex column level and preserving initial order

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how can I merge two (or more) pandas dataframes like this:

**df1:**

```
   |    ant    |       nac       |
   | uyn | yam | qlv | udb | rkd |
---|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
X1 |  6  |  1  |  8  |  4  |  5  |
X2 |  4  |  5  |  3  |  5  |  4  |
X3 |  2  |  9  |  2  |  9  |  4  |
```

**df2:**

```
   |    baz    |       ant       |
   | rjv | ifz | uyn | pgc | yam |
---|-----|-----|-----|-----|-----|
X1 |  2  |  1  |  7  |  3  |  8  |
X2 |  9  |  7  |  3  |  1  |  4  |
X3 |  2  |  1  |  6  |  2  |  9  |
```

into a dataframe like this:

```
   |             ant             |       nac       |    baz    |
   |    uyn    |    yam    | pgc | qlv | udb | rkd | rjv | ifz |
   | df1 | df2 | df1 | df2 | df2 | df1 | df1 | df1 | df2 | df2 |
X1 |  6  |  7  |  1  |  8  |  3  |  8  |  4  |  5  |  2  |  1  |
X2 |  4  |  3  |  5  |  3  |  1  |  3  |  5  |  4  |  9  |  7  |
X3 |  2  |  6  |  9  |  2  |  2  |  2  |  9  |  4  |  2  |  1  |
```

I've tried to use `concat`, but then stuck sorting items in each level in the right order (as items are not alphabetically sorted). Tried `reindex` and ended with a lot of empty columns because of intersections of *ant* on *udb` and such.

Maybe I'm over complicating things. Is there some easier way to do this?

Comment: [how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: No code shown that you tried, maybe add a [mre] to be refined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat) with `keys` then [`reorder_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html#pandas-dataframe-reorder-levels):

```
new_df = (
    pd.concat((df1, df2), axis=1, keys=('df1', 'df2'))
        .reorder_levels([1, 2, 0], axis=1)
)
```

Optional programmatically assign keys for the "or more" case:

```
dfs = (df1, df2)
new_df = (
    pd.concat(dfs, axis=1, keys=map('df{}'.format, range(1, len(dfs) + 1)))
        .reorder_levels([1, 2, 0], axis=1)
)
```

```
   ant     nac         baz     ant        
   uyn yam qlv udb rkd rjv ifz uyn pgc yam
   df1 df1 df1 df1 df1 df2 df2 df2 df2 df2
X1   6   1   8   4   5   2   1   7   3   8
X2   4   5   3   5   4   9   7   3   1   4
X3   2   9   2   9   4   2   1   6   2   9
```

Then try successive [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html#pandas-dataframe-reindex) to "sort" by first occurrence across:

```
new_df = (
    new_df.reindex(
        columns=new_df.columns.get_level_values(0).drop_duplicates(),
        level=0
    ).reindex(
        columns=new_df.columns.get_level_values(1).drop_duplicates(),
        level=1
    )
)
```

```
   ant                 nac         baz    
   uyn     yam     pgc qlv udb rkd rjv ifz
   df1 df2 df1 df2 df2 df1 df1 df1 df2 df2
X1   6   7   1   8   3   8   4   5   2   1
X2   4   3   5   4   1   3   5   4   9   7
X3   2   6   9   9   2   2   9   4   2   1
```

---

`df1` and `df2` used:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({('ant', 'uyn'): {'X1': 6, 'X2': 4, 'X3': 2},
                    ('ant', 'yam'): {'X1': 1, 'X2': 5, 'X3': 9},
                    ('nac', 'qlv'): {'X1': 8, 'X2': 3, 'X3': 2},
                    ('nac', 'udb'): {'X1': 4, 'X2': 5, 'X3': 9},
                    ('nac', 'rkd'): {'X1': 5, 'X2': 4, 'X3': 4}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({('baz', 'rjv'): {'X1': 2, 'X2': 9, 'X3': 2},
                    ('baz', 'ifz'): {'X1': 1, 'X2': 7, 'X3': 1},
                    ('ant', 'uyn'): {'X1': 7, 'X2': 3, 'X3': 6},
                    ('ant', 'pgc'): {'X1': 3, 'X2': 1, 'X3': 2},
                    ('ant', 'yam'): {'X1': 8, 'X2': 4, 'X3': 9}})
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried exactly that but sort_index just sorts them alphabetically, I need them in order they appear in dataframes.